# Visual Basic Unable to Read from Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've a project where I should my form to an Excel file and write column from this file as the contents of a ComboBox (cmbbxContinent) here is the code

```
Function GetDatafromExcelSheet(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal Sql As String) As DataTable
    Dim MyConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source='" & FilePath & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection
    MyCommand.CommandText = Sql
    da.SelectCommand = MyCommand
    da.Fill(dt)
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = GetDatafromExcelSheet("C:\Users\MZ\Atlas\database\atlas.xls", "select distinct Continent from [data$]")
    cmbbxContinent.DataSource = dt
    cmbbxContinent.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
    cmbbxContinent.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
    cmbbxContinent.SelectedIndex = 1
End Sub
```

The problem is:
- I've seen the same code in a tutorial and it worked 
- There is no problem with the path of the file 
- There is no error in the tool name (cmbbxContinent)
- The message is get when I start debugging is:
"'data$' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."
and this message happens at the statement "da.Fill(dt)"
-I am using Visual Studio 10; Can this be the problem as the tutorial was on an older version?

Sorry I'm very new at Visual Studio and Visual Basic , Please help
Thanks

Comment: maybe not "data$" but "sheet1$", and also you may need an ";HDR=yes" added to your Extended properties, didn´t have the time to try this.

Comment: Yeah it's Sheet1$ , thanks a lot for the help man